# Zwinkern vs Blinzeln

Tags: translation, difference, verb, vocabulary

In English, we have **blink** and **wink** where **wink** is a voluntary action. In German, which one is the voluntary one and which one is not? When should I use one over another? Or are both of them is a synonym?

Comment: Hello Logos, the politeness of hellos and thank yous is not desired here, because it distracts from the question and I therefore deleted it from your question.

Comment: I see, understood. Thank you for telling me @Iris

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summary:

> The words *blinzeln* and *zwinkern* tell nothing about the number of eyes involved and careful investigation proves volition is no absolute criterion either!

### On the number of eyes involved

The conjectures voiced in the other answer about the number of eyes involved  in *anblinzeln* are completely misguided. You can definitely say:

> Aus seinem verbliebenen Auge blinzelte mich der Pirat verständnislos an.

When I entered *blinzeln m*, my browser already proposed *blinzeln mit einem Auge*. It is used *[here](https://www.rund-ums-baby.de/kinderarzt/Blinzeln-nur-mit-einem-Auge_374203.htm)* and *an* doesn’t change anything about the number of eyes involved. *An* *can* be used to emphasise the voluntary nature but can also be directional.

I was initially inclined to agree with the claim in the comments that *zwinkern* involves only one eye, but  more research shows this is not strictly required. Not only are there numerous counter examples  [counter example](https://www.elitepartner.de/forum/frage/wuerdet-ihr-das-zwinkern-benutzen-und-was-drueckt-ihr-damit-aus.76853/), [second counter example](https://www.planet-liebe.de/threads/m%C3%A4nner-und-zwinkern.205719/), [third counter example](https://www.gutefrage.net/frage/was-bedeutet-es-wenn-ein-maedchen-mit-beiden-augen). The [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zwinkern) also lists:

> nervös, vielsagend, vertraulich [mit **den Augen**] zwinkern

To put the nail in the coffin, [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ13716#XGZ13716) also notes:

> allgemein gebräuchlich und verbreitet die engere bedeutung 'mit **den augen** zwinkern, mit den augenlidern zucken, sie zusammendrücken'

Grimm also mentions usages I never heard in the 20th century:

> herr Barbarossa zwinkerte mit dem munde

### On volition

It is my experience as a native speaker that *zwinkern* is **usually** voluntary and *blinzeln* *involuntary*. *Blinzeln* typically occurs when we wake up or when light blinds us. Thus it *typically* involves both eyes. But careful investigation reveals neither voluntary nature nor eye number strictly differentiates these words. Same holds for *anblinzeln* where *an* fulfils the role of English *at*. This can still be involuntary, and unintentional just as *gape at*/*anglotzen*  or *ankotzen/puke at* or *anstinken* can. See below.

Indeed **there are examples of blinzeln as a voluntary action** in [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB08500#XGB08500):

> man biege nunmehr den kopf zurück und blinzle mit den augen. Göthe 52, 181;

Grimm also notes:

> die augen halb öfnen und blinken lassen, oft um damit zu winken, aber auch unklar sehen, geblendet, halbblind sein

On the other hand **there are examples of *zwinkern* as an involuntary action**. One of Grimm’s [definitions for *zwinkern*](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ13716#XGZ13716) reads:

> eine unbewuszte zuckende bewegung der augenlider

Response to comments:
Anglotzen can be unintentional too Simply consider:

> Er nahm mich nicht wahr, sondern glotzte mich aus toten Augen an.

Comment: "Glotz/Kotz mich nicht an!" assumes the other person is doing it on purpose and I would always assume/expect an intention with verbs like anglotzen or ankotzen (I've never heard anstinken).

Comment: @Iris They are *typically* but not necessarily intentional. Compare: „Er nahm mich nicht wahr, sondern glotzte mich aus toten Augen an“.

Comment: @Ludi, What about this then? *Every arbitrary amount of time elapsed, we blink our eyes unconsciously*. Would you still use _blinzen_ for this action? By the way, I just realized that the stemm of _blinzeln_ is _blinz_, it sounded like the English _blind_... does _blinzeln_ is an action always triggered by "blinding light"?

Comment: @Logos good question. Let me think about it. Blinzeln is not always triggered by light. As you can see from Goethe’s example it can be voluntary. It is usually etymologically connected to blinken/blink. It might also be connected to blind. Grimm makes such connection

Answer (score 4):

Roughly

- blinzeln — *to blink*
- zwinkern — *to wink with one eye*

Well, those are obvious, they are cognates. But there's also

- anblinzeln, zublinzeln — *to wink with both eyes, to flirt with the eyes*

Comment: Anblinzeln doesn’t imply anything about the number of eyes involved! Rather, the *an* corresponds to English *at*.

Comment: @Ludi, I disagree. I think, you can't "(an/zu-)blinzeln" with only one eye. If only one eye is used, I would use "(zu-)zwinkern"

Comment: @Iris “Der Pirat erwachte und blinzelte mich aus seinem verbliebenen Auge Verständnislos an” ist sicherlich möglich. Da Blinzeln meist instinktiv geschieht, assoziiert man damit  tendenziell beide Augen. Eher trifft jedoch eine Unterscheidung zwischen instinktiv und absichtlich, wie sie der op vernimmt. Die Beidäugigkeit ist keine Notwendige Bedingung!

Comment: @Iris https://www.rund-ums-baby.de/kinderarzt/Blinzeln-nur-mit-einem-Auge_374203.htm

Comment: @Ludi, beides (Augenklappe, motorische Störung) sind aber sehr besondere Fälle, an die ich nicht denken würde. Außerdem wird in beiden Fällen explizit erwähnt, dass es eine besondere Situation mit nur einem Auge ist.Ich würde daher bei "anblinzeln" immer von der Norm = 2 funktionierende Augen ausgehen.

Comment: Both *anblinzeln* and *zublinzeln* are **voluntarily**. That's the most important part. And the difference to *zwinkern* is *zwinkern* only involves one eye. If it's both eyes, it's not *zwinkern* any more.

Comment: @Iris Natürlich sind das besondere Fälle, die konstruiert wurden um zu zeigen, daß die Behauptung nicht gilt.

Comment: @Janka anblinzeln is not necessarily voluntary. As for *zwinkern* I would agree it is done with one eye. But you claimed something else, namely that anblinzeln necessarily involves two eyes.